# Changing Awesome CV layout

Tags: awesome-cv

I use `awesome-cv.cls` and find it amazing. However, there is one thing I'd like to change.

For one section only (`Eduction`), I'd like to get rid of bullet-points. Here's how they look:

[image]

Source looks that way:

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#1#3#4}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}}
      {\ifempty{#2#3}
          {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
          {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
            \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
        \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

If I put empty section of `{<description>}`, I get the correct result, however, the spacing between two entries is too big:

[image]

To avoid this, I've made a little hack, namely I put `\vspace{-1mm}` between the entries. Now it is ok. However, I'd be happy to know how this could be fixed.

Here's MWE along with my hack:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\fontdir[fonts/]
\newcommand*{\sectiondir}{resume/}

\definecolor{text}{HTML}{000000}
\begin{document}
\begin{cventries}
    \cventry
    {Bachelor of Science in Computer Science, GPA: 3.5/4.0}
    {Northeastern University}
    {Boston, MA}
    {May 2019}
    {
        % \begin{cvitems}
        %     \item {TEST}
        % \end{cvitems}
    }
    \vspace{-1mm}
    \cventry
    {Bachelor of Science in Computer Science, GPA: 3.5/4.0}
    {Northeastern University}
    {Boston, MA}
    {May 2019}
    {
        % \begin{cvitems}
        %     \item {TEST}
        % \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This type of 'hacks' is regularly found in LaTeX documents, they are more or less normal/accepted (the `\vspace{-2.0mm}` at the start of `\cventry` in the awesome-cv source is an example of this). Also, default LaTeX macros themselves are often full of rather obscure positioning tricks. So if this solution works for you then I would suggest to leave it as it is and enjoy the result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago I was facing the same issue. To solve it, I modified the `\cventry` command as displayed below. The idea is to check if the description (`#5`) is empty, and to add content (`multicolumn`) only if the description itself is not empty. Carriage returns are moved accordingly.

```latex
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} }
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} }
    \ifempty{#5}
      {}
      {\\\multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution. Thanks!